# How to merge the child object and create unique parent Object from a Arraylist if parents are unique but have diffener child

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 class as parent and child

```
public class Accounts implements Serializable{  
private String accountCode;
private String number;
private List<Details>  details;
}
public class Details implements Serializable{   
private String accode;
private String description;
private String currency;    
}
```

I have below details in arraylist

20230725;444072744;IN909098223;TestData1;EUR
20230801;444072743;IN909098224;TestData2;INR
20230725;444072744;IN909098225;TestData3;USD

parents are same with id  20230725 but they have different child.
I want final result like

20230725;444072744;{IN909098223;TestData1;EUR}, {IN909098225;TestData3;USD}
20230801;444072743;IN909098224;TestData2;INR

This data is in a Arraylist
I have done like below

```
int duplicateCount = 0;
    List<Accounts> updatedAccount = new ArrayList<Accounts>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < Accounts.size(); i++) {  
      for (int j = i+1; j < Accounts.size(); j++) {
        if(Accounts.get(i).getAccountCode().equals(Accounts.get(j).getAccountCode())) {
          duplicateCount++;
          Accounts.get(i).getDetails().addAll(Accounts.get(j).getDetails());
          updatedAccount.add(Accounts.get(i));
          }
        }
    }
    if(duplicateCount == 0){
      updatedAccount.add(Accounts.get(i));
    }
```

i am geting

```
20230725;444072744;{IN909098223;TestData1;EUR}, {IN909098225;TestData3;USD}
20230801;444072743;IN909098224;TestData2;INR
20230725;444072744;IN909098225;TestData3;USD
```